# Alternate positive and negative numbers in array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array consisting of equal number of positive and negative numbers (0 being considered as positive). Rearrange the elements such that positive and negative numbers are placed alternatively, in such a way that it should be in-place and order of elements should not change. Is there a solution better than O(n2)?

Comment: With extra array it is O(n).

Comment: Guys, he mentioned he had a O(n^2) solution and is looking for better one.

Comment: If it is a homework problem, kindly bother to give me an answer with O(n) or O(nlogn) time and O(1) space.

Answer (score 3):

With array, I don't know whether a solution better than O(n^2) is possible because any deletion and insertion to an array is of O(n) time complexity.

**Note that here we are not swapping values as in fast sorting algorithms, but deleting and inserting to new position in array.**

O(n) time solution is possible if you maintain your sequence as a linked list.

Keep 2 pointers. One for scanning the list, and other for keeping track of swapping index.

Just scan the list for alternating + and - numbers. In case you encounter 2 consecutive +ve numbers, then stop the tracking pointer at the last node scanned. Keep scanning the list with your scanning pointer until you encounter a negative number.

Now delete the negative index node from its original position and insert the negative index node before the tracking pointer position. Increment the tracking pointer by 1 step.
These operations can be done in O(1) time in a linked list.

Similarly for negative values. At any time you can have only either extra positive of negative numbers.

Just keep track of the insertion position.

Comment: It's not in-place, in-place implies better space consumption than O(n)

Comment: This should also work with an array and two indices.

Comment: Can "Stable sort" technique applied in this case ?

Comment: With stable sort you can form an array of elements with all -ve elements before all +ve positive elements in O(nlogn) time. But how do you proceed further?

Comment: Basically what I came up with myself. Check if you have two numbers with the same sign and replace the second one with a !sign one.

Comment: I don't really find "assume we're given a different data structure than the one we're actually given" to be a valid answer. Doing this with a linked-list is, in my opinion, fairly trivial. Regarding your first statement, you can also say a sort consists of insertions and deletions (i.e. insertion sort), but some sorts use swaps instead and gets O(n log n) running time.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes you are right. Using linked list is not valid here. Can I vote to re-open this question? I have been working hard trying to solve it, but can't see a good efficient solution using arrays. As others have pointed out, separating -ve and +ve numbers can be done in O(nlogn) time as this link shows http://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/array-stable-partition/. But how to proceed further? Any hints?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal It shouldn't be reopened as OP hasn't shown an attempt at solving the problem him/herself (regardless of whether or not the question is actually interesting). But from there you do [this](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7528760). I believe the one that says "This is in place array transpose" is O(n log n). I don't think any of the others are.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for the link! It has some nice ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if the input array is `[-1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, 9]`, then the

```
output should be [9, -7, 8, -3, 5, -1, 2, 4, 6]
```

The solution is to first separate positive and negative numbers using partition process of QuickSort. In the partition process, consider 0 as value of pivot element so that all negative numbers are placed before positive numbers. Once negative and positive numbers are separated, we start from the first negative number and first positive number, and swap every alternate negative number with next positive number.

```
// A C++ program to put positive numbers at even indexes (0, 2, 4,..) 
// and negative numbers at odd indexes (1, 3, 5, ..)
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype for swap
void swap(int *a, int *b);

// The main function that rearranges elements of given array.  It puts 
// positive elements at even indexes (0, 2, ..) and negative numbers at 
// odd indexes (1, 3, ..).
void rearrange(int arr[], int n)
{
    // The following few lines are similar to partition process
    // of QuickSort.  The idea is to consider 0 as pivot and
    // divide the array around it.
    int i = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < 0)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }

    // Now all positive numbers are at end and negative numbers at
    // the beginning of array. Initialize indexes for starting point
    // of positive and negative numbers to be swapped
    int pos = i+1, neg = 0;

    // Increment the negative index by 2 and positive index by 1, i.e.,
    // swap every alternate negative number with next positive number
    while (pos < n && neg < pos && arr[neg] < 0)
    {
        swap(&arr[neg], &arr[pos]);
        pos++;
        neg += 2;
    }
}

// A utility function to swap two elements
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// A utility function to print an array
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%4d ", arr[i]);
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {-1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, 9};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    rearrange(arr, n);
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
Output:

    4   -3    5   -1    6   -7    2    8    9
```

Time Complexity: **O(n) where n is number of elements in given array.**

Auxiliary Space: **O(1)**

Comment: Order of elements shall still not be maintained after swapping -ve and +ve elements.

Comment: Accoring to the OP, the input array contains equal number of positive and negative elements.

Comment: Assuming there are as many positive as negative items in your array.